# extract keywords using grepl

Tags: r, dplyr, extract, grepl

I have a data called 'data' and I want to create a new subset 'data_1' if columns 'apple' or 'orange' contains the keyword 'sweet'.

```
library(tidyverse) 
data_1 <- data %>%
      grepl ('sweet',apple,)
```

it worked the first time but it doesn't work now. Also, I want to apply the condition in either the column apple or orange, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `filter` with `if_any` (if we want to return rows where the keywork 'sweet' is found in either of the columns.) or use `if_all` (if we want the rows having 'sweet' in both the columns)

```
library(dplyr)
data_1 <- data  %>%
           filter(if_any(c(apple, orange), ~ grepl('\\bsweet\\b', .x,
ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

If we want to keep other 'sweetheart' as well, take out the word boundary (`\\b`)

```
data_1 <- data  %>%
           filter(if_any(c(apple, orange), ~ grepl('sweet', .x,
ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

---

Or may also use `|` if there are only two columns

```
data_1 <- data %>%
             filter(grepl('\\bsweet\\b', apple, ignore.case = TRUE)|
                    grepl('\\bsweet\\b', orange', ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Or another option is to `paste` the two columns and apply `grepl` once

```
data_1 <- data %>%
          filter(grepl('\\bsweet\\b', paste(apple, orange),
         ignore.case = TRUE))
```

EDIT:

1. Added word boundary (`\\b`) in the pattern so that it wouldn't match `sweetheart`
2. By default `ignore.case = FALSE` in `grepl`.  If we want to match either case, use `ignore.case = TRUE`

Comment: thanks! some follow up questions. (1) is 'sweet' case sensitive ? , (2) also let's say some content in column apple or orange says 'sweetheart', is it being extracted? so does 'sweet' only extract the exact word or anything that contains sweet

Comment: @Dr.KnowNothing updated the post.  Hope it helps

Comment: @Dr.KnowNothing `grepl` returns a logical vector of TRUE FALSE if it finds the keyword 'sweet' or not.  and `filter` the rows containing those words in the 'apple' or orange.  If you need to extrat use `sub` or `stringr::str_extract` etc.  From your post, I assume that you want to filter the rows?

Comment: yes. I want to filter the rows that only contain sweet. I would want to keep sweetheart as well.

Comment: @Dr.KnowNothing isn't that the one that worked earlier? i.e. without using `\\b`